# HTML Comments to detect IE6 and IE7

Tags: html, templates, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, conditional-comments

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
I am using IE6
<![endif]-->
```

That works.

How do I do **"or"** IE7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you, for whatever reason, what to only test for IE6 or IE7, and maybe have some other conditions for IE5 elsewhere, there is also support for other operators:

```
  <!--[if (IE 6)|(IE 7)]>
    This is IE 6 or IE 7!
  <![endif]-->
```

Check out the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) which has better documentation than Quirksmode on this.

Answer (score 4):

you can do

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
I am using IE less than or equal to version 7
<![endif]-->
```

Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html#link3 for detailed options..

Comment: Thanks, that helped me out but there looks like an error in your reply, it seems it should be [if lte IE 7] where lte stands for less than or equal.

Comment: @edwinbradford, thanks for catching that.. it was indeed wrongly typed.. (*i have corrected the answer*)

Answer (score 0):

same exact format. just change the ie version. Refer to here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx